# OAuth when you own all the clients, the authorization server and the protected APIs

Tags: android, ios, oauth, .net-core, oauth-2.0

I'm wondering whether OAuth is the right fit for me.

I need to write a REST service (or REST services) that can be accessed by several clients. All clients will be written by me. The service will be written by me. And as for the Authorization server, it will only use local accounts, no external log ins at all.

Given this I feel like implicit flow and the authorization code grant flow are not the right fit for me. I feel like using a redirect in this scenario would be silly, given that I write the clients, am the identity provider, and so on.

Should I maybe not use OAuth at all? What should I use instead? Or if I am to use OAuth, would I have to use ROPC in order to avoid the redirects?

If OAuth is the answer, are there any solutions I could use? Azure AD B2C? Or should I write my own, and if so, does any one have any resources on how to do that using .NET Core?

I should mention that we will also be using long-running services where client credentials flow would be a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit flows is just one of the ways OAuth2 defines for a client app to acquire a token it will subsequently use to call a service. It should be used by browser-embedded (SPA) apps only. [A blog I wrote lists the other flow types and when to use them](http://mrochon.azurewebsites.net/2019/06/04/choosing-an-oauth2-grant-flow/)

Yes, you should consider using OAuth2 unless you don't care who calls your services because nobody else can (you are running on a completely closed network inside Fort Knox) or you cannot imagine anyone would want to call them. (sorry about my sense of humor). The purpose of OAuth2 is to manage permission of apps calling each other. Its advantage vis a vis other protocols is that it supports most common scenarios (daemon clients, web apps, IOT devices, etc.)